# Can we change the namespace case?

Tags: managed-package, namespace

We are building a managed package and we have set a namespace for the package and the package is almost ready for security review.

Our marketing department have come back to us to say that we need the namespace to be in Title case. Can we change the namespace from full caps to Title case?

What are my options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to discard the current package and namespace, register a new namespace via a new org, link the namespace to your dev hub and create a new package. Not to mention any code-level or metadata references to the namespace prefix would have to be changed (along with things like sfdx-project.json, project-scratch-def.json and other build files, plus any automation you have that uses the namespace at all).

It is not worth it.

IMHO, I would also say that the namespace prefix is a development decision, not a marketing one. The namespace prefix is internal and not visible to ordinary users (just to admins and implementers who need to know the namespace for integration or object model/Apex API access).

UPDATE: As pointed out by @kurunve in a comment here, you cannot have namespace "ABC" and "Abc" since Salesforce ignores case from the availability checking perspective, so you would have to actually change more than case in updating the namespace.

Comment: Namespace is also case-insensitive, you can not register both Namespace1 and NAMESPACE1 at the same time

Comment: Thanks.. i guess we will stick with what we have. Sometimes the url does have the namespace listed and thats where the marketing team noticed it